# setBackingStoreLocation

Tags: java, unit-testing, google-app-engine

What is the base path of [setBackingStoreLocation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting/javadoc/com/google/appengine/tools/development/testing/LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig.html#setBackingStoreLocation%28java.lang.String%29)?

I've [setNoStorage](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting/javadoc/com/google/appengine/tools/development/testing/LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig.html#setNoStorage%28boolean%29) to false.
I see datastore-indexes-auto.xml being created in \WEB-INF\appengine-generated(not \war\WEB-INF\appengine-generated).

I've tried providing an empty string, null, not setting it at all, and an absolute path, all with both a file name specified as well as with just a path specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's relative to the project root. I just wasn't attempting to persist any objects.

The following will create the file in the root of the project.

```
LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig dsConfig = new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig();
dsConfig.setBackingStoreLocation("local_db.bin");
```

The following with create the file in C:

```
LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig dsConfig = new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig();
dsConfig.setBackingStoreLocation("C:\\local_db.bin");
```